# Use SSH to connect to a Windows OS in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, window

In Windows machine, I installed Ubuntu in my Oracle VM VirtualBox.

In Ubuntu, if I want to connect to another Linux machine:

```
$ ssh username@ip
```

But if I want to connect to my Windows machine, that way doesn't work!

So how can I connect to a Windows machine using `ssh` from Ubuntu (i.e. in my vm virtualBox)?

@bodhi.zazen thank your answer. After I install `openssh` for Windows, when I use `ssh username@ip`, there is the following error:

```
root@lime-VirtualBox:/home/lime# ssh sikaiwei@192.168.1.103

                        ****USAGE WARNING****

This is a private computer system. This computer system, including all
related equipment, networks, and network devices (specifically including
Internet access) are provided only for authorized use. This computer system
may be monitored for all lawful purposes, including to ensure that its use
is authorized, for management of the system, to facilitate protection against
unauthorized access, and to verify security procedures, survivability, and
operational security. Monitoring includes active attacks by authorized entities
to test or verify the security of this system. During monitoring, information
may be examined, recorded, copied and used for authorized purposes. All
information, including personal information, placed or sent over this system
may be monitored.

Use of this computer system, authorized or unauthorized, constitutes consent
to monitoring of this system. Unauthorized use may subject you to criminal
prosecution. Evidence of unauthorized use collected during monitoring may be
used for administrative, criminal, or other adverse action. Use of this system
constitutes consent to monitoring for these purposes.


sikaiwei@192.168.1.103's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
sikaiwei@192.168.1.103's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
sikaiwei@192.168.1.103's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

And in my Windows machine, I reedit the `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH for Window/etc/sshd_config` like that:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

But I still get the same error.

When I connect my Ubuntu using `ssh` from my Windows machine, the error

```
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)
```

still exists.

Comment: Do you want to connect *from* a Linux host to a Windows host (it's Windows, not window), or do you want to connect *from* a Windows host to a Linux host?

Comment: Are trying to connect to a windows server or is windows the client and Linux the server ?

Comment: I want to connect from a Linux host to a Windows host..

Comment: The machine you connect FROM is the client, the machine you connect TO is the server. Sounds as if you need a Windows ssh server.

Comment: yes..I am installing a Windows ssh server --openssh...

Comment: Is "sikaiwei" your user name on the Windows server ? What password are you using (use your windows login password I assume).

Comment: oh,no!"sikaiwei" is not."myth" is my user name on the Windows server.But I try it again,the error still exist..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring a SSH daemon on Windows.

Comment: sorry.But I don't know where I can go except this site...

Comment: You could try [su] or *very possibly* [sf] (though I think [su] would be a better bet). You can flag your question for moderator attention if you want it migrated; please don't simply repost it elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry.How can I do to flag my question for moderator attention and migrate it to Super User?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same way, but you need to run a ssh server on the Windows machine (and make sure you are not firewalling the connection).

See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292/what-are-some-good-ssh-servers-for-windows

Edit: If you need a windows ssh client, use PuTTy

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Answer (score 0):

Windows machine should run some SSH server, for example I like this one: freeSSHD (http://www.freesshd.com/), which suit my needs. 
Just you have to respect Windows style folders, etc. Simple: You will get into a DOS prompt.
Other functions of freeSSHd will enable you to connect there by SFTP, mount Windows files and folders s a local drive via `sshfs`, manage allowed users, manage access keys (if necessary), and you can simply choose to run freeSSHd as a service, so the Windows machine has not to be logged in.

**Update on the edit**

Do you have allowed some AllowUsers or AllowGroups in the config? Do you log by your Linux root or you use windows user/password? Do not forget, you are running this software in hostile Windows environment. This user should be allowed to run certain things in Windows, therefore try it with an admin account first.